# We can use CSS Sprites, but doesn't that require all the images be made into block or display: block elements?

Tags: css-sprites, sprite

I'd like to use CSS Sprites, but I haven't used it in massive scale before, and seems like  when all the images are being displayed using CSS Spirites (image as background), then it must be inside a `div` or `span` with `display: block` so that it can have a width and height?

If so, then isn't it messy that, before, as an `<img>`, it can flow as an inline element naturally, but now, it has to be `floated`.

It might be able to be shown as `inline-block`, but I think it is not well supported by all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [this fix for inline-block when spiriting](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/) (although I ignore the vendor style for Firefox as modern FF plays nice).

FTA:

```
display:-moz-inline-stack;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
```

Note that IE is generally fine as long as the element hasLayout.